# Stuck on this union / except

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to find the best way to proceed with this, for some reason it is really tripping me up.

I have data like this:

```
transaction_id(pk)  decision_id(pk)   accepted_ind    
A                    1                NULL
A                    2                <blank>
A                    4                Y
B                    1                <blank>
B                    2                Y
C                    1                Y
D                    1                N
D                    2                O
D                    3                Y
```

1. Each transaction is guaranteed to have decision 1
2. There can be multiple decision possibilities (what-if's) type of scenarios
3. Accepted can have multiple values or be blank or NULL but only one can be accepted_ind = Y

I am trying to write a query to:

1. Return one row for each transaction_id
2. Return the decision_id where the accepted_ind = Y or if the transaction has no rows accepted_ind = Y, then return the row with decision_id = 1 (regardless of value in the accepted_ind)

I have tried:
1.  Using logical "or" to pull the records, kept getting duplicates.
2.  Using a union and except but can not quite get the logic down correctly.

Any assistance is appreciated.  I am not sure why this is tripping me up so much!

Adam

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  Basically the `WHERE` clause says:

Where Accepted = 'Y'
OR
There is no accepted row for this transaction and the decision_id = 1

```
SELECT Transaction_id, Decision_ID, Accepted_id
FROM MyTable t
WHERE Accepted_ind = 'Y'
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2
                WHERE Accepted_ind = 'Y'
                and t2.Transaction_id = t.transaction_id)
    AND Decision_id = 1)
```

Comment: thanks!  The query makes complete sense and gives me the exact results I was seeking!  I believe I looked at this so long that I started down the wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses `ROW_NUMBER()` and therefore will only work on SQL Server 2005 or later

I have modified your sample data as as it stands, all `transaction_id` have a `Y` indicator!

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( 
    transaction_id NCHAR(1), 
    decision_id INT, 
    accepted_ind NCHAR(1) NULL 
)

INSERT @t VALUES
    ( 'A' , 1 , NULL ),
    ( 'A' , 2 , '' ),
    ( 'A' , 4 , 'Y' ),
    ( 'B' , 1 , '' ),
    ( 'B' , 2 , 'N' ),  -- change from your sample data
    ( 'C' , 1 , 'Y' ),
    ( 'D' , 1 , 'N' ),
    ( 'D' , 2 , 'O' ),
    ( 'D' , 3 , 'Y' )
```

And here is the query itself:

```
SELECT transaction_id, decision_id, accepted_ind FROM ( 
SELECT transaction_id, decision_id, accepted_ind, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY transaction_id 
        ORDER BY
            CASE
                WHEN accepted_ind = 'Y' THEN 1
                WHEN decision_id = 1 THEN 2
                ELSE 3
            END
    ) rn
FROM @t
) Raw
WHERE rn = 1
```

Results:

```
transaction_id decision_id accepted_ind
-------------- ----------- ------------
A              4           Y
B              1            
C              1           Y
D              3           Y
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` clause gives a 'priority' to each criterion you mention; we then `ORDER BY` to pick the best, and take the first row.

Comment: This what I was starting to build. The nice thing about it is you can build additional Ranking paramters. e.g. accepted, than blank, then first

Comment: Thanks!  this worked as well, I never even considered this approach but I really like it!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a neater/more efficient query, but I think this will get the job done. It assumes the table name is Decision:

```
  SELECT CASE 
         WHEN accepteddecision.transaction_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
         accepteddecision.transaction_id 
         ELSE firstdecision.transaction_id 
       END AS transaction_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN accepteddecision.decision_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
         accepteddecision.decision_id 
         ELSE firstdecision.decision_id 
       END AS decision_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN accepteddecision.accepted_ind IS NOT NULL THEN 
         accepteddecision.accepted_ind 
         ELSE firstdecision.accepted_ind 
       END AS accepted_ind 
FROM   decision 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   decision AS accepteddecision 
                        WHERE  accepteddecision.accepted_ind = 'Y') AS 
                       accepteddecision 
         ON accepteddecision.transaction_id = decision.transaction_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   decision AS firstdecision 
                        WHERE  firstdecision.decision_id = 1) AS firstdecision 
         ON firstdecision.transaction_id = decision.transaction_id 
GROUP  BY accepteddecision.transaction_id, 
          firstdecision.transaction_id, 
          accepteddecision.decision_id, 
          firstdecision.decision_id, 
          accepteddecision.accepted_ind, 
          firstdecision.accepted_ind
```

Comment: The sub queries are not required just do an And in your JOIN e.g. `JOIN Decision AcceptedDecision ON AcceptedDecision.transaction_id = Decision.transaction_id AND AcceptedDecision.accepted_ind = 'Y` Also you could use `COALESCE` instead of the CASE Statements

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, the following uses `UNION` and `EXCEPT` (plus a `JOIN`) as specified in the question title:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT * FROM (
              VALUES ('A', 1, NULL),
                     ('A', 2, ''),
                     ('A', 4, 'Y'),
                     ('B', 1, ''),
                     ('B', 2, 'Y'),
                     ('C', 1, 'Y'),
                     ('D', 1, 'N'),
                     ('D', 2, 'O'),
                     ('D', 3, 'Y'), 
                     ('E', 2, 'O'), -- smaple data extended
                     ('E', 1, 'N')  -- smaple data extended
             ) AS T (transaction_id, decision_id, accepted_ind)
     ) 
SELECT * 
  FROM T
 WHERE accepted_ind = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT T.* 
  FROM (
        SELECT transaction_id
          FROM T
         WHERE decision_id = 1
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT transaction_id
          FROM T
         WHERE accepted_ind = 'Y'
       ) D
       JOIN T 
          ON T.transaction_id = D.transaction_id
             AND T.decision_id = 1;
```